# Do we always use indefinite article before any course or degree like "M.A."?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article, acronyms

I've seen people using "a/an" before *MA, BA, B.Tech, BE, MBA,* etc. I want to know if "a/an" is always necessary to be used before the names of courses or degrees. Is it incorrect if I write *MA* without the indefinite article "a/an"?Are the following sentences correct or incorrect?

> I want to do MA.
>
> I am doing B.tech.

Comment: In American English, we don't "do" a degree, we "get" a degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use of the indefinite article is certainly most common before the names of such qualifications:

> I want to do an MA.
>   I am doing a BTEC (or B.tech).

It seems incorrect to me to **not** use an indefinite article before them.

This is because they are shortened versions of the real words (MA = Master of Arts, for example), and we have omitted the word 'degree' or 'qualification' after them.